# My AsyncTask is stuck in doInBackground() forever

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i have a program where i consult google spreadsheets, i do it in a AsyncTask but is very slow so i want to put a ProgressDialog, i show it on onPreExecute method but my program can´t execute doInBackground method, howewer i can see that app enters in this method thaks to Log.i, but don´t do nothing, i can see Progress dialog  but nothing else, it´s like an infinite bucle

My AsyncTask is like this:

```
private class GestionDatos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();


        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Trabajando", "Espere por favor");
    }


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("com.banshee");
        ArrayList<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();
        String idAnterior = "idAnterior";
        try {

            String urlString = "My URL";

            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            ListFeed feed = service.getFeed(url, ListFeed.class);

            for (ListEntry entry : feed.getEntries()) {
                CustomElementCollection elements = entry
                        .getCustomElements();
                String id = elements.getValue("Codigo");
                if (idAnterior.compareTo(id) != 0) {
                    idAnterior = id;
                    String name = elements.getValue("Profesor");
                    nombres.add(name);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return nombres;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgress.dismiss();
        values = result;
    }

}
```

Sorry for my bad English and please be patient, i'm a noob android programmer

Comment: get rid of `super.onPostExecute(result);`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer petey, but unfortunately my ProgressDialog keep running and running and running......thank you very much :)

Comment: oh, how'd I miss this, get rid of `super.onPreExecute();` as well

Comment: Thanks for your time but my app still don´t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last it seems a hardware problem, i execute the code in a much powerfull computer and works, maybe due to heavy work my application freeze? i don´t know, thanks

Comment: This is a valid answer.  If one is dissatisfied with the situation, the response should be to vote to close the question as a one-time/irreproducible situation, not to flag the answer in which the **asker of the question** states the **actual resolution**.  Or if someone feels that there is a better answer or that this is not a wise resolution, then post an answer or leave a comment.  But don't flag an asker for reporting *what worked for their own question*.